# Firebase | Cocoa Pod with framework

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods-1.0.1

Our code structure is as follows,

We have a Framework A for iOS , which Application going to link and embed as a link as a binary inside Xcode,

Framework A pod file is

```
target 'iosFramework' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for iosFramework
  pod 'Firebase'

end
```

Now in the 'Application' where i am going to include 'iosFramework' i am getting error "FirebaseInstanceId" cannot be found,

Any help,

Basically i wanted to know, Is this correct way to make use of pod ?

What should be ideal practice if the code structure is something like this,

I am on Xcode 7.3 and pod 1.0.1

Comment: Any luck ? I'm facing the same issue